# Mudar arquivo CRT para byte

Tags: java, android, certificado-digital

Preciso converter um arquivo `.crt` em byte para poder mandar por socket. Esse código funciona em Java, mas como eu escreveria ele no Android?

```java
Path path = Paths.get("sdcard/certificado.crt");
byte[] certificado = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desculpa demora pessoal consegui fazer faz um tempo so que esqueci de postar aqui minha resposta. Meu codigo ficou assim

```
    File f = new File(cert); // o cert é o caminho do meu certificado ex: sdcar/download/certificado.crt
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(f);
    byte[] certificado = new byte[(int) f.length()];
    input.read(certificado);
```

Answer (score 2):

*Código não testado*

Com minhas buscas obtive o seguinte:

```
public static byte[] convertFileToByteArray(File f)
{
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try
    {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024*8];
        int bytesRead =0;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1)
        {
            bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Fonte: 
http://androidsnippets.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/how-to-convert-a-file-to-byte-array/

Mas também encontrei estes:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466469/convert-android-graphics-path-object-to-byte-and-back
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466908/create-a-arraylist-of-byte-array-in-android

E esse que acredito não ser bem o que você quer, mas é útil:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/fileoutputstream/write-byte-array-to-file-with-fileoutputstream/

Answer (score 2):

Bom, você pode utilizar a biblioteca [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) para alcançar isso. De atenção as funções [`IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) e [`FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File file)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray%28java.io.File%29).

---

Se você não optar por utilizar o que foi sugerido acima você pode utilizar essa função abaixo.

```
public static byte[] getFileBytes(File file) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;
    InputStream ios = null;
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ios = new FileInputStream(file);
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = ios.read(buffer)) != -1)
            ous.write(buffer, 0, read);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ous != null)
                ous.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //
        }
        try {
            if (ios != null)
                ios.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // 
        }
    }
    return ous.toByteArray();
}
```

<sub>[Código encontrado nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9431216/1608936)</sub>